# How to deal with the inconsistency between the posts file and the actual webpage on github?

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

everybody, I am new to github and build a simple blog on it. However, when I add a new file to the posts directory, the actual website will not always be updated immediately(sometimes it does), I thought it is because of the cache of the Chrome, but after I cleared up the cache, the webpage still has no changes at all. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a look at your repository at https://github.com/wsstriving/wsstriving.github.io

What I found is a website that use Jekyll architecture. So, for some useful tips you can refer to [Jekyll documentation here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/).

I've try to build your site locally, using [Github pages setup](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) and I discovered that your _posts/2015-05-24-markdown.md has some trouble with two fenced code blocks :

````
```flow
st=>start: Start
op=>operation: Your Operation
cond=>condition: Yes or No?
e=>end

st->op->cond
cond(yes)->e
cond(no)->op
```
````

and

````
```seq
Alice->Bob: Hello Bob, how are you?
Note right of Bob: Bob thinks
Bob-->Alice: I am good thanks!
```
````

Both a referencing languages (`flow` and `seq`) that are not in the [github linguist grammars](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor/grammars).

That's what makes the Github pages build failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wanted to test on this site, so I copied a whole document generated by a local markdown editor, maybe the grammars are not exactly the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you generate your site it will take about 10 minutes for it to go live. Subsequent builds should only take seconds from the time you push the changes to your GitHub repository.

However, depending on [how your have your domain configured](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages), there may be extra time for the Github CDN cache to break.

Comment: Thanks, more than one hour has passed, the page still doesn't appear.And I didn't use other domain names, here is my site, [wsstriving](http://wsstriving.github.io) . It will help a lot if you can help me check it out, thanks